# Are there any latin-alphabet languages written right-to-left?

Tags: list-of-languages, alphabets

Are there any languages using the Latin alphabet characters which are written right-to-left?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not nowadays, but at least one of the earliest Latin inscriptions was written alternating between left to right and right to left. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Latin#Fragments_and_inscriptions Since the Latin alphabet looked quite different at the time and this style of writing also involved mirroring the letters themselves, we should probably not count this.

Comment: That is correct. The Forum inscription at least is written that way. Of course you can debate whether it is in the Latin alphabet stricto sensu.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I suppose you can write any Latin-based script in mirror writing, as Leonardo da Vinci famously did, but otherwise I think the answer to your question is "no".

Comment: Is it possible that the earliest Archaic Latin was written right-to-left like Etruscan from which the Latin alphabet descended?

Comment: Boustrophedon is a natural way to do any kind of lettering; it has defects for the reader but it's easier for the carver. Earliest Latin writing would be more likely boustrophedon than right-to-left.